# Check if generating a Visual Studio solution or Makefile from CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

How can I know in my CMakeLists.txt if I'm generating a Visual Studio solution or a Makefile?

I need to add external projects to the solution like this:

```
INCLUDE_EXTERNAL_MSPROJECT(cs-tests ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cstests/cstests.csproj)
```

But I only want to do it when calling

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Visual Studio 12 2013"
```

not when I call:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
```

Answer (score 15):

CMake `MSVC` variable can be set even if the generator is other than `Visual Studio` (e.g. `Ninja` on Windows).

To check if CMake generator is Visual Studio (i.e. msbuild), the following did the trick:

```
if (CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Visual Studio")
    # Do Visual Studio specific stuff
else()
    # Other stuff
endif()
```

Answer (score 8):

The name of the generator is stored in `CMAKE_GENERATOR`. It should contain the exact string given by the `-G` option.

The `MSVC` variable should also be set to `TRUE`, as should `MSVC12` and `MSVC_IDE` (though I can't confirm that from [the documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) at the moment.)

Comment: Note that `MSVC` is not set initially - it is likely set after the call to `project`. Meanwhile `CMAKE_GENERATOR` is always set within `CMakeLists.txt` - to a string such as "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64". This is useful as setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` should be done before the call to `project`, but perhaps only on Windows; e.g. for vcpkg.cmake.

Comment: MSVC variable is not always defined, I recommend to match "if (CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Visual Studio")"